# BB Web Works giving error as "error feature cannot be found in any extension(blackberry. pin .memo)" while packaging the app

Tags: packaging, blackberry-webworks

I am new to BlackBerry Web Works.I am following the instruction for development given on development site.While packaging the Application I am getting this error in command prompt : "[ERROR] feature cannot be found in any extension(blackberry. pin .memo)".

Before going to this step I have already created project folder with config.xml and index.html and also zip file of application components properly.And now trying to package the application.But I am getting error like:

[image]

Please help me to figure out this error.
Thanks

Comment: Some more things I found about this is at this place "C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry WebWorks SDK 2.3.1.5\ext" there must be a folder with name "blackberry.pim.memo" containing "library.xml" file with a folder "blackberry".This must contain a sub folder with name "pim" which again having sub folder with name "memo" which ultimately contain files related to "memo".Still I am getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution after a lot of searching and analogy.

This error occurs when either we have added some feature in config.xml which we are not using  in our application or when we are using same feature but not defined in "feature" tag in config.xml. It is the same case with "spinner" ,"sms" etc.

In my case it was because of "memo"  ,which I was defining in config.xml but didn't use any Contact feature in my Application.So it producing error like "feature cannot be found in any extension(blackberry. pin .memo)".